# Как в этой функции работает логический оператор?

Tags: javascript, операторы

У меня есть такая функция. В итоге в консоль выводит 10.

```js
var foo = 1; 
function bar() { 
    if (!foo) { 
        var foo = 10; 
    } 
    console.log(foo); 
} 
bar();
```

Вопрос: Почему? Логический оператор "не" сначала берет переменную и преобразовывает к логическому типу (`1 --> true`), а потом переводит полученный логический тип данных к противоположному (`true --> false`).

Дальше в условии if мы получаем false, следовательно, условное ветвление не должно выполняться. Почему происходит выполнение if, в котором переменной присваивается новое значение?

Comment: так переменная сначала будет `undefined` в том месте

Comment: @entithat в каком месте, в условии if? А до этого же значение переменной было определено - `var foo = 1`, как может быть undefined?

Comment: значение 1 подставлялось бы, если бы не было `var foo` снова внутри `bar`. В нашем случае, джс как-бы "переносит" переменную `foo` в начало скоупа и делает ее undefined по умолчанию. Потом проходит проверка и тогда уже для этой переменной будет установлено значение 10.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: @entithat сделайте Ваш комментарий ответом, пожалуйста

Comment: @entithat если переменные объявлять с помощью `let`, эффекта поднятия не возникает (в коде выше выводится 1). Получается что это очередная особенность работы `var`?

Comment: Да, особенность var, но на практике очень трудно нарваться на такое)

Comment: @entithat а можете ещё пояснить такой момент? Получается, что натыкаясь на foo в самом условии if, переменная foo объявляется в пределах функции, потом браузер ищет переменную foo в пределах функции, находит undefined, которое переводится в true. Выводится 10. Правильно я вас поняла?

Comment: Считайте, что у вас будет так: `function bar() { var foo; if (!foo) { foo = 10; } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте подробнее о Поднятии [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

В вашем случае код выглядит так:

```
var foo = 1; 
function bar() { 
    var foo;
    if (!foo) { 
        foo = 10; 
    } 
    console.log(foo); 
} 
bar();
```

Переменная `foo` (которая внутри функции `bar`) будет определена только лишь после условия. Но почему же в условие попадает значение не 1, а `undefined`?

Потому что, срабатывает такое понятие, как "поднятие". т.е. декларация переменной `foo` (которая внутри функции `bar`) переносится в начало области видимости - т.е. функции `bar`:

С такого кода:

```
function bar() {
    console.log(foo); // undefined
    var foo = 10;
    ...
}
```

формально будет такой:

```
function bar() {
    var foo;
    console.log(foo); // undefined
    foo = 10;
    ...
}
```

Такое свойство работает как для функций так и для переменных (но только тех, которые через `var`)